# WordPress - Show children of the visited category only

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I've created a menu using `wp_list_categories()`, but it displays categories with all of their children visible. My client wants me to have it show children of the current category only.

So let's say that we have a tree of categories:

**FIRST CATEGORY**

**SECOND CATEGORY**

**THIRD CATEGORY**

If someone clicks the first category, then children of that category should be visible:

**FIRST CATEGORY**

- child1
- child2
- child3

**SECOND CATEGORY**

**THIRD CATEGORY**

As soon as he clicks on a child category, for example child1 it should look like this:

**FIRST CATEGORY**

- child1

  - child1 of child1
  - child2 of child1
- child2
- child3

**SECOND CATEGORY**

**THIRD CATEGORY**

And finally, as soon as he clicks on, for example, child2 of child1:

**FIRST CATEGORY**

- child1

  - child1 of child1
  - child2 of child1

    - child1 of child2 of child1
- child2
- child3

**SECOND CATEGORY**

**THIRD CATEGORY**

So if he is, for example, at the depth of 3 categories then all other categories on the same level should have their children invisible. As soon as he selects one of the child categories it should show it's children then.

It just blows my mind, and I have no idea how to do that with jQuery/css. WordPress classes seem useless here. Could you please help me with that? It'd be great if it could be done with basic WordPress arguments for that `wp_list_categories()` function:

```
$args = array(
'show_option_all'    => '',
'orderby'            => 'name',
'order'              => 'ASC',
'style'              => 'list',
'show_count'         => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 0,
'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
'child_of'           => 0,
'feed'               => '',
'feed_type'          => '',
'feed_image'         => '',
'exclude'            => '',
'exclude_tree'       => '',
'include'            => '',
'hierarchical'       => 1,
'title_li'           => __( '' ),
'show_option_none'   => __( 'No categories' ),
'number'             => null,
'echo'               => 1,
'depth'              => 0,
'current_category'   => 0,
'pad_counts'         => 0,
'taxonomy'           => 'category',
'walker'             => null
);
wp_list_categories( $args );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li.categories .children
{
  display: none;
}
li.categories .current-cat > .children,
li.categories li.current-cat-ancestor > .children
{
  display: list-item;
}
```

This should be enough. :)

After 3rd level you may also need jQuery due to WordPress bug...

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.current-cat').parents('.cat-item').addClass('current-cat-ancestor');
});
```

Comment: ehh, it's working only to 3rd level, 4 levels of cats breaking everything... I think that is WordPress bug.

Comment: I'v created a core ticket witch patch to fix it (without jQuery workaround) - if you star it, maybe we can see it in 4.1. :)
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30635